# WebGPU sample displays white canvas on Chrome v113

Tags: google-chrome, webgpu

## Graphics Feature Status

- Canvas: Hardware accelerated
- Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Enabled
- Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
- Compositing: Hardware accelerated
- Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
- OpenGL: Enabled
- Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
- Raw Draw: Disabled
- Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
- Video Encode: Hardware accelerated
- Vulkan: Enabled
- WebGL: Hardware accelerated
- WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
- WebGPU: Hardware accelerated

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I enabled `vulkan` on Windows Chrome. Setting it to `default` solves the problem.